# Search Through Links in HTML File

Tags: php, html, search

I'm working on a project where users can upload files and the uploaded files store at cdn network and the link of file is store at localhost in html, SQL Database, json, csv, txt format. Let's take the example of html file.

How links store in HTML File Example :

```
http://cdn.example.com/folder/test/Green Wood.png
http://cdn.example.com/folder/test/Setting.jpg
http://cdn.example.com/folder/test/quote.zip
```

**What I actually want to do is**

that when user search for keyword let's example ***green*** then it should search in html file and when the file name found it return the file name as a anchor text and that link to that file like

```
<a href="http://cdn.example.com/folder/test/Green Wood.png">Green Wood</a>
```

Problem is that client do not want to store or not able to store any other data expect the link of uploaded file. The files are uploaded like no links are repeated or duplicated, and they just prefer that html file should be the source file.

Comment: Your `HTML File Example :` isn't "HTML"... it's more plain text.

Comment: The html file contents the plain text as shown in example.

Comment: I don't understand: What data in which format do you have and what do you want to get from this data in whish format when you search them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if this snippet helps?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['html-links'])) {
  $linkText= $_POST['html-links'];
  $match= $_POST['match'];

  $exprMatch= '|(http://.*'.$match.'.*)|i';

  preg_match($exprMatch, $linkText, $arrMatches);

 } else {
   $arrMatches= array();
   $linkText= $match= '';
 }
 ?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
HTML link text:<br />
<textarea name="html-links" style="width:500px;height:100px;"><?php print $linkText; ?>           
</textarea>
<br /><label>Search for: 
<br /><input name="match" value="<?php print $match; ?>"/>
<br /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<br />
Matches: <br />
<pre><?php print_r($arrMatches); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Modified the above example to create a list of all found matches as HTML links: http://snipt.org/BqB0

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted. Thank you very much.